# Live Metrics Stream for Xamarin Mobile Application

Tags: azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-application-insights

I am facing some issue regarding Azure Application Insights
I am working in Xamarin Forms and for Live matrix they want to install the Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web
[image: App Insights]

Can anybody know how can I Enable the Live Matrix Stream for Mobile Applications (Xamarin Forms)
Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Application Insights for Xamarin.Forms` SDK is deprecated, you can refer to this [doc](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Xamarin).

Please switch to [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net/) or consider [MobileCenter](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/app-center/).